# Math basic five properties question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We define a relation $R\subseteq\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ where $(a,b)\in R$ exactly when $a+2b$ is divisible by $3$. Determine how many of the basic five properties of reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, irreflexivity and asymmetry are satisfied by R.

My thoughts:
reflexivity is ok as if $a=b$ or $b=a$ ther $a+2b$ will become $3a$ or $3b$ and still satisfy the requirement.

for irreflexivity i only have the definition with me :
A relation R on a set A is irreflexive if for each element x in A, x is not related to itself by R. I am not sure the answer is...

for transitivity and symmetry, i really can not find any restriction on this..

Please help.

**New updates:**

Symmetry satisfied due to the answer by Mcihak, then asymmetry not satisfied.

reflexivity satisfied due to the answer by Svinepels, then irreflexivity  not satisfied.

transitivity satisfied due to the answer by Svinepels.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your proof of symmetry looks strange. I think you proved that relation is reflexive instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflexivity: You want to determine whether $(a,a) \in R$ for all integers $a$, i.e. if $a+2a = 3a$ is always divisible by $3$. Is this always true?

Transitivity: Assume that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$, i.e. $a+2b$ and $b+2c$ are both divisible by $3$. Does it follow that $a+2c$ is divisible by $3$, i.e. $(a,c) \in R$? Here you should use the fact that any linear combination of multiples of 3 is again a multiple of 3. Try to find a linear combination of $a+2b$, $b+2c$ and $3b$ which gives $a+2c$.

Comment: Transitivity satisfied:a + 2b = 3k
b + 2c = 3l

a + 2c = 3k - 2b + 3l - b
       = 3k + 3l - 3b
       = 3 (k+l-b)

Comment: Reflexivity satisfied as well

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry: You must prove $(a,b) \in R$ imply $(b, a) \in R$, i.e. $a+2b=3k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and you must prove that $b+2a$ is divisible by 3. Try to substitute $a=3k-2b$ and you will see...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, after apply a = 3k - 2b then b+2a = b + 6k - 4b = 6k-3b then it satisfy the Symmetry

Comment: That's right. You are welcome!